# Adding Space counter to program

Tags: c++, c

I have a program that replaces spaces with dash. Now I need to be able to count the amount of spaces that have been replaced and print it. here is my coding for the spacing replace.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100], *space;
    {
    printf("Enter a string here: \n"); //Enter a string in command prompt
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin); //scans it and places it into a string
    space = string;

    while (*space == ' '? (*space = '-'): *space++);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

and this is the code to count the number of space.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int count( const std::string& input )
{
    int iSpaces = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
        if (input[i] == ' ') ++iSpaces;

    return iSpaces;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input;

    std::cout << "Enter text: ";
    std::getline( std::cin, input );

    int numSpaces = count( input );

    std::cout << "Number of spaces: " << numSpaces << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure how to put the 2 combined together? Can anyone help?

**UPDATE:**

I have changed my code to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int numSpaces = 0;

int main()
{
    char string[100], *space;
    {
    printf("Enter a string here: \n"); //Enter a string in command prompt
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin); //scans it and places it into a string
    space = string;

    while (*space == ' '? (*space = '-'): *space++);

    printf("%s\n", string);

    }
    while (*space)
{
   if( *space == ' ')
   { 
      *space = '-';
      ++numSpaces;
   }
   ++space;

   printf("%f\n", numSpaces);
}

    getchar();
}
```

Problem with the result. I keep getting loads of Zeros

[image]

Comment: Funny that you wrote C code for one part and in C++ for the other.

Comment: Exctly what I thought :D

Comment: *copied C code from one person and C++ from another?

Comment: My program is in C (The 1st part) then found the space counter coding somewhere which is in c++.

Comment: It is not clear what language is to be used for the program.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Apparently the OP's looking for a translation of the C++ code to C ...

Answer (score 1):

You can either use member function replace of class std::string in a loop or you can use standard algorithm replace applied to your string. As for me I would choise the standard alforithm.

for example

```
std::replace( input.begin(), input.end(), ' ', '-' );
```

Comment: As for the counter then again you can use standard algorithm std::count provided that you are writing the program in C++.

Answer (score 0):

To stay with [c](/questions/tagged/c), extend your while loop accordingly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100], *space;
    int numSpaces = 0;

    printf("Enter a string here: \n"); //Enter a string in command prompt
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin); //scans it and places it into a string
    space = string;

    // Replacement and counting are done within the following loop IN ONE GO!
    while (*space)
    {
        if( *space == ' ')
        { 
            *space = '-';
            ++numSpaces;
        }
        ++space;
    }
    printf("%s\n", string);
    printf("Replaced %d space characters\n", numSpaces);

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Added the result below. Keep getting loads of zeros

Comment: numSpaces is an int. %f is the wrong format specifier for an int.

Comment: printf("%d\n", numSpaces); doesn't solve it

Comment: @AbarthGT Don't get your comment?!? See my edits, I extended the sample to the complete program ...

Answer (score 0):

To keep with the spirit of your first snippet:

```
int replaced = 0;
while (*space == ' '? (replaced++, *space++ = '-'): *space++);
```